# how to get name of node on which my code is executing in azure fabric service?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

How can I get the name of the machine on which my code is running in a Azure Fabric Cluster for logging purposes?

I am running a c# code in a fabric cluster with some nodes. I would like to log some information along with the machine name. I am using FabricRuntime, but it is not helping me. What is the best way to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [NodeContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.servicecontext.nodecontext?view=servicefabric-5.5.216#System_Fabric_ServiceContext_NodeContext) property of the [ServiceContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.servicecontext?view=servicefabric-5.5.216).

So, given the context of a service (either stateful or stateless) or actorservice you can call `context.NodeContext.NodeName` to retrieve the node name.

The `ServiceContext` has a lot of oher properties as well that can be useful for logging purposes.

For a complete example of getting node and service details see [this](https://github.com/DeHeerSoftware/Azure-Service-Fabric-Logging-And-Monitoring/blob/master/src/ServiceFabric.Logging/LoggerFactoryBuilder.cs) repo.

Answer (score 3):

```
FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().NodeName
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I was facing the same kind of situation and I found out that using the fabric client was very helpful. Since I am learning to use it now; the answer may lack some extensive details.
This is a sample code you can further find out the details on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient?view=azure-dotnet) link and use it according to the requirements

```
    var fabricClient = new FabricClient();
    var apps = fabricClient.QueryManager.GetApplicationListAsync().Result;
    foreach (var app in apps)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Discovered application:'{app.ApplicationName}");

        var services = fabricClient.QueryManager.GetServiceListAsync(app.ApplicationName).Result;
        foreach (var service in services)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Discovered Service:'{service.ServiceName}");

            var partitions = fabricClient.QueryManager.GetPartitionListAsync(service.ServiceName).Result;
            if (service.ServiceKind != System.Fabric.Query.ServiceKind.Stateful )
            {
                continue;
            }
     }
```

It is very helpful in querying the service fabric for required information. Now for the case of nodes you can simply do a query through the query manager like this and further use the node information to query deeper.

`var nodes = fabricClient.QueryManager.GetNodeListAsync().Result;`

I hope it helps someone else like me still on the same question.