# How to get total service fabric nodes

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, metrics, service-fabric-stateless

I need to create service availability metrics for a service fabric service. If all nodes are up then need to report OK state, any node is down then Warning state and multiple nodes are down then Error state. I am little confuse on getting the total number of nodes(UP+Down). I have written the below code and it's not giving any metrics as of now.

```
public async Task LogServiceFabricHealthMetrics(ServiceContext serviceContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var fabricClient = new FabricClient();
                var nodeList = (await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetNodeListAsync()).ToList();

                var serviceName = serviceContext.ServiceName.LocalPath.Split('/')[2];
                var nodesRunningApplication = new List<Node>();

                foreach (var node in nodeList)
                {
                    var nodeApplicationList = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetDeployedApplicationListAsync(node.NodeName);
                    var nodeApplication = nodeApplicationList.FirstOrDefault(p =>
                        p.ApplicationName.LocalPath.Split('/')[2] == serviceName);

                    if (nodeApplication != null)
                    {
                        nodesRunningApplication.Add(node);
                    }
                }

                if (nodesRunningApplication.Count == nodeList.Count)
                {
                   //All nodes are up and report OK state          
                }
                else
                {
                    if (nodesRunningApplication.Count >= nodeList.Count - 2)
                    {
                      //One node is down and report Warning state                    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      //More than one node is down and report Error state                      
                    }
                }

                await Task.Delay(this.interval * 6 * 60 * 1000);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. Is the code not working? What have you tried?

Comment: @PeterBons The code is not working. Not sure if this is correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//string currentNode = ServiceContext.NodeContext.NodeName;
   var SfClient = new FabricClient();
   var SFnodeList = (await SfClient.QueryManager.GetNodeListAsync()).ToList();

   foreach (var node in SFnodeList)
     {
                Console.WriteLine($"Node Name: {node.NodeName}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Node Status: {node.NodeStatus}");
     }

    var SvcName = ServiceContext.ServiceName.LocalPath.Split('/')[1];
    var nodesRunningApp = new List<Node>();
        foreach (var node in SFnodeList)
          {
             var nodeAppList = await SfClient.QueryManager.GetDeployedApplicationListAsync(node.NodeName);
             var nodeApp = nodeAppList.FirstOrDefault(p =>
              p.ApplicationName.LocalPath.Split('/')[1] == SvcName);
              if (nodeApp != null)
               {
                    nodesRunningApp.Add(node);
               }
           }
```

**Nodes**

[image]

**To Fetch all the running apps**

```
 var currentApps = await SfClient.QueryManager.GetApplicationListAsync();
```

- Once the service information is fetched, you can check the nodes.

```
 var currentNodes = SfClient.QueryManager.GetNodeListAsync();
 var nodeInformation = await SfClient.QueryManager.GetNodeLoadInformationAsync("nodeName");
```

For further information refer to this [Blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/running-net-core-application-in-azure-service-fabric-cluster/) and SO [Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959312/how-to-get-name-of-node-on-which-my-code-is-executing-in-azure-fabric-service)

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh. I also added the "HealthState == OK" check for the deployed application before adding into the nodesRunningApp. But it's always coming as Unknown. Do you happen to know any other attribute which works here for the health check?